# Amount of processes in fork() statements including program

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I am learning about forks and processes in linux and have a question concerning the initial parent process. Is this initial parent process considered the program?

For example this code where I create 2 forks

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    printf("%d *\n", getpid());
    fork();
    printf("%d *\n", getpid());
    fork();
    printf("%d *\n", getpid());
    sleep(20);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

From what I know there would be an initial parent process(which I believe is the program), and then there would be the initial fork creating a child process.

This leaves 2 processes. Then the other fork creates 2 more child processes for 5 processes total including the initial parent process.

From that understanding, the total number of child processes would be 3(2^2-1) and the total processes created besides the initial parent process would be 4.

Is my thinking correct?

Also, what would cause a fork to fail?

Comment: You're basically saying 2+2=5. First you have 2 ("This leaves 2 processes" which includes the parent process as per the previous paragraph), then you add 2 ("Then the other fork creates 2 more child processes"), and end up with 5 somehow ("for 5 processes total including the initial parent process").

Comment: @SanderDeDycker yes because I was treating the program seperate from initial parent process but the initial parent process is the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, each `fork()` call creates exactly one additional process. In this example You'd have a total of 4 processes, including parent process.

EDIT:
I recommend reading manual for methods that You learn and use e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

You'll find there all the explanation, including possible failure reasons.

Comment: Is the program the initial parent process?

Comment: Yes.The process created by `fork()` is copy of the initial process ("program").

Comment: @DarkApostle — I suggest you think of "the program" as the file on disk that is executed.  When the program is run, there is an initial process that executes an in-memory version of the program stored on disk.  When the process forks, there are two almost identical processes both running the same program (but with slightly different data).  Rinse and repeat.  But "program" is on disk and "process" is in memory is reasonably accurate (swapped out processes are perhaps on disk, except that disk is now a solid-state disk or SSD, which is a special sort of memory, …).